# How to grant privileges to use DBMS_OUTPUT in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-12c

`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`, `DBMS_OUTPUT` work perfect in my user, System or DBA. But when i create new user, it's not work! 
How to grant privileges to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connect system / [PASSWORD] as sysdba;
grant create session to [USER];
grant execute on DBMS_OUTPUT  to [USER] with grant option;
```

I can solved with it.

Comment: Default oracle installations shouldn't have to explicitly grant execute on `dbms_output`, unless you have somehow dropped the public synonym or revoked the grant execute to public.

Comment: @ruudvan May be not. I create simple user and just grant Connect and Resource for it. I don't know anything else like public synonym ...